# Is it possible to mount a webdav share on windows as something other than FAT?

Tags: apache, centos, webdav, pydio, sabredav

I have an apache server running on Linux. I have the dav module enabled. When I am on my windows computer, I mount it as a network drive. However, it shows the filesystem as FAT.  Is there a way to change that to either NTFS or something else that will display the disk size correctly and speed up the file transfers?

Answer (score 2):

If windows shows the filesystem as `FAT`, it simply means that there's a bug in Windows. When windows talks to the webdav server, it's neither FAT nor NTFS. It's talking 'WebDAV', and the underlying storage mechanism is hidden and irrelevant.